# How to use cropper.js in typescript modular project?

Tags: typescript, modular, jspm

I am using jspm install npm:cropper

which installs cropper and adds "cropper": "npm:cropper@^2.0.1" to package.json aslo i could find it under \jspm_packages\npm folder

But its not loading in network tab. any idea what am missing?

P.S:- I did not find the type definitions for cropper.js so i have declared the cropper like

```
declare var cropper: any;
declare module "cropper" {
    export = cropper;
}
```

and imported it as import * as cropper from 'cropper'; which is not giving any error, but still no luck with cropper loading.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm doing:

import * as Cropper 'cropper/dist/cropper.min.js';


but I cant' do:
new Cropper(..);


it says: Cropper is not a function

Comment: nevermind, i imported cropper, not cropperjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps. The first step is to install cropper which is what you did when you added the package to `package.json`. The second step is to actually load the package - see https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs how to do that.

If you want to import the package yourself, you should not use `import ... from 'cropper'`but

```
var cropper = require('cropper');
```

because otherwise TypeScript compiler will check if the module is written in TypeScript and if it is located under `node_packages` folder.

Comment: using var cropper = System.import("cropper"); did load the cropper.js require does't work for some reason.

Comment: Yes, `require` is used in commonjs. (it can work with systemjs too: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#requirejs-support) but `System.import('cropper')` is proper way for systemjs

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem, but haven't been able to figure it out.  I import like this and the file DOES get downloaded, but I can't call new Cropper(...);
---------->
import * as Cropper from 'cropper/dist/cropper.min.js';

Answer (score 0):

> But its not loading in network tab. any idea what am missing

It will not be loaded *unless its required*. E.g.

```
var foo = require('cropper');
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: I did add import * as cropper from 'cropper' to the file where am using cropper but it says can't find the module?

Comment: For `import` to work it needs to be declared as a TypeScript module